# How to resolve vulnerability CVE-2022-3715 for bash package in Debian 11.7?

Tags: linux, bash, debian, package-management

I have built a Docker image with Debian 11.7, and I ran the Trivy Docker scanning tool. The report displayed a vulnerability, [CVE-2022-3715](https://security-tracker.debian.org/tracker/CVE-2022-3715), for the bash package.

- As per this [page](https://security-tracker.debian.org/tracker/CVE-2022-3715), the issue is fixed with bash version 5.2-1. But when I try to install 5.2-1 version of bash, I got the error saying "version version number for bash was not found".
- And I see it was fixed in newer version of Debian (bookworm) which is going to be released in future. But how can we fix this issue without waiting for new version of Debian?

Answer (score 3):

The issue has been qualified as minor and won’t be fixed in Debian 11 or lower. If you want to fix it in your container image, you have a few options:

1. Base your image on Debian 12 — the release is due in less than a month and the contents of your image are unlikely to change significantly if you start using it now.
2. Pull in the Debian 12 package manually. This might feel safer than the previous option, but you‘ll end up with an unsupported setup which is liable to cause other problems.
3. Build bash from source.

I recommend the first. (Really, if I were in your situation I would check the possible uses of bash in the image, and probably ignore the CVE. But I understand that may not be an option for you.)