# Debian Vs Ubuntu as base image for Docker images

Tags: debian, ubuntu, docker

Our current docker images are based on Debian 11. We are using Trivy vulnerability scanning tool before publishing the image to registry. Trivy shows there are around 100 plus High and Critical vulnerabilities in Debian latest image, but for Ubuntu latest, we don’t see any High and Critical issues.

What are the advantages and disadvantages of switching from Debian to Ubuntu as the base image for all our Docker images?"

And is there any possibility of facing compatibility issues while all users start using images based on Ubuntu (switching from Debian)? If yes, what could be those?

Comment: What is the use case, what is needed? Are you certain that there are no false positive vulnerabilities? Can you add more details.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately Trivy doesn’t seem to be all that relevant for Debian-based images (arguably because Debian’s metadata relies on messages which aren’t machine-analysable). A Trivy scan of an up-to-date Debian 11 image flags 76 vulnerabilities; I haven’t looked at all 76, but the first few aren’t exploitable or have been qualified as minor:

- [CVE-2011-3374](https://security-tracker.debian.org/tracker/CVE-2011-3374) doesn’t need fixing in Debian
- [CVE-2022-3715](https://security-tracker.debian.org/tracker/CVE-2022-3715) is qualified as minor (as discussed in [How to resolve vulnerability CVE-2022-3715 for bash package in Debian 11.7?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/746484/86440))
- [CVE-2022-0563](https://security-tracker.debian.org/tracker/CVE-2022-0563) doesn’t affect Debian because Debian doesn’t ship the vulnerable programs
- [CVE-2016-2781](https://security-tracker.debian.org/tracker/CVE-2016-2781) is qualified as minor
- [CVE-2017-18018](https://security-tracker.debian.org/tracker/CVE-2017-18018) is mitigated by kernel hardening

On top of that, Trivy counts CVEs per binary package, so for example CVE-2022-0563 is counted multiple times (`bsdutils`, `mount`, `util-linux`).

The situation in Ubuntu isn’t all that different, but the metadata provided more accurately reflects the ultimate situation in the distribution; see for example [CVE-2022-0563](https://ubuntu.com/security/CVE-2022-0563) which is marked “not vulnerable”, with exactly the same situation as Debian.

My experience with security scanners is that they can be useful, but it takes a fair amount of work to understand their methodology and derive an accurate picture. As has been mentioned elsewhere, Debian and Ubuntu both receive security updates.

You should base your decision regarding which base image to use on which base image best serves your purposes, not which base image gets the best score in whatever security scanning tool you’ve chosen. I wouldn’t expect many compatibility issues switching between Debian and Ubuntu base images; but the result would depend on the specific contents of your container images.